# Update handle if else condition

Tags: if-statement, amazon-dynamodb, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I have the below scenario to be handled :

1. If a is not present in dynamodb, then update a with received value and not b.
2. If a is present in dynamodb, then, update b with received value and not a.

Can someone tell me how this can be handled?

Comment: Two conditional expressions wrapped in a transactional write?

Comment: Transactional write doesn't allow for transactions on same item.

Comment: I tried using if_not_exists but that handles only if part and not else.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Condition Expressions in dynamoDB to manipulate data . for more help there is below link of documents

you can use Amazon Documentation it will help you more than any documents :
Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ConditionExpressions.html

Comment: Condition expressions can be used when we have only if condition  here, I've both if and else, I mean, if a is present, do 1 thing, else, do, another thing.

Comment: Also, condition expression throws conditionalcheckfailedexception, so, else part is not handled.